# JS: TypeError: Cannot find function keys in object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following in apps script:

```
function getQAs() {
    return [

      { "Do you have any pictures ?|1 ": {"yes":2,"no":3 } },
      { "Do you have any pictures ?|2 ": {"yes":2,"no":3 } },
      { "Do you have any pictures?|3 ": {"yes":2,"no":3 } },
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to build a function that will search through the keys of The objects for a number. I'm testing with the number 1 .When I run:

```
function testQA() {
  var qa = getQAs();
  var matches = qa.keys().filter(function(row) { //ONLY CHECKED ROWS.
    Logger.log(row)
    return row.indexOf('1') == true;
  });

  Logger.log(matches);
}
```

I get

> JS: TypeError: Cannot find function keys in object . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `keys` is not a prototype method. It only exists on the 'static' `Object` class. So you would need `Object.keys(qa)`

Comment: You are executing `keys()` on an `array`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava also that

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Which would be totally okay because there is a `.keys()` method defined for `Array` ([`Array.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys)) ;)

Comment: @Andreas And which would result in `qa.keys(...).filter is not a function`

Comment: if you're just filtering array, what is the point of calling .keys?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I didn't say that it makes a lot more sense with the function, only that it would be okay (at least in browsers that support `Array.prototype.keys()`) :)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking but try `qa.filter(a => Object.keys(a)[0].includes("1"))`

Comment: Why use such a weird format that requires parsing. Got an object, make it useful.

Comment: @epascarello, I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `for...in` loop to get the keys of an object. I devised a simple loop through keys to determine if the value existed within the key, then pushed out a filtered array

```
function testQA() {
  var qa = getQAs();

  function getRow(row_identifier) {
  var filtered = [];
    qa.forEach(function(v) {
      for(var k in v) {
       if(k.indexOf(row_identifier) > 0) filtered.push(v);
      }
    });
         return filtered;
  }

   return getRow(row_identifier);
}
```

```js
function getQAs() {
  return [

    {
      "Do you have any pictures ?|1 ": {
        "yes": 2,
        "no": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "Do you have any pictures ?|2 ": {
        "yes": 2,
        "no": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "Do you have any pictures?|3 ": {
        "yes": 2,
        "no": 3
      }
    },
  ]
}

function testQA() {
  var qa = getQAs();

  function getRow(row_identifier) {
  var filtered = [];
    qa.forEach(function(v) {
      for(var k in v) {
       if(k.indexOf(row_identifier) > 0) filtered.push(v);
      }
    });
         return filtered;
  }
      console.log(getRow(1));
      console.log(getRow(2))
      console.log(getRow(3))
}
testQA();
```

Comment: Apps Script is basically JS 1.6. No includes, no let, no iterators, no arrow syntax. It does have map, filter, reduce, some, and every support.

Answer (score 1):

## Just playing around with your question

I'm not that good with objects so I thought it would be fun to play around with this and see what I can learn. I have no expectation of having my answer chosen, I just thought it might be valuable to a less experienced programmer, like myself.

```
function getQAs() {
  var qa=[{"Do you have any picture?|1":{yes:"2",no:"3"}},{"Do you have any picture?|2":{yes:"4",no:"5"}},{"Do you have any picture?|3":{yes:"8",no:"9"}}];
  return qa;
}

function testQA(row) {
  var row=row || 3;
  var qa = getQAs();
  Logger.log(qa);
  var qA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<qa.length;i++) {
    qA.push(Object.keys(qa[i]));
  }
  Logger.log(qA);
  for(var i=0;i<qA.length;i++) {
    if(qA[i].toString().indexOf(row)>-1){
      var rv=JSON.stringify(qa[i]);
      var t1=qA[i];
      var t2=qa[i];
      var yeses=t2[t1].yes;
      var nos=t2[t1].no;
      var t3={yes:yeses,no:nos};
      return t3;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully, someone can learn something from this by single stepping through the program. It returns an object with the number of [yeses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yes) and [noes](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noes) for the selected object.